# Azure Dev Ops: How can I require a boolean field to be true before state can be changed?

Tags: azure-devops, boolean, tfs-workitem, workitem

I am modifying a workitem using the XML model on Azure Dev Ops server 2022.

I have a short checklist, made up of checkboxes, like

x Independent
x Negotible
x Valuable
x Estimable
x Small
x Testable

Before the state can be changed to ready, all the checkboxes must be set to true.

How can I write rules for this in the WIT?

I tried to use MATCH and PROHIBITEDVALUES, but these rule elements are not working with booleans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add your custom field for validation purposes:

```
<FIELD refname="MyCorp.Validation" name="Custom Validation" type="String">   
       <WHEN field="MyCorp.Independent" value="false">  
           <COPY from="value" value="Independent false">  
       </WHEN>  
</FIELD>
```

Then use it as prohibited values in the state:

```
<STATE Your state definition >>>>>>  
    <FIELD refname="MyCorp.Validation">  
        <PROHIBITEDVALUES for="userGroupName" not="userGroupName" expanditems="true | false" filteritems="excludegroups">   
          <LISTITEM value="Independent false" />  
        . . .   
        </PROHIBITEDVALUES>
    <FIELD>
```

Comment: So by mapping the boolean to a string, validation becomes possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Minor detail: Tailing slash missing in 
 <COPY from="value" value="Independent false">